# Can you nest collection calls? MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, coffeescript

Can you nest collection calls in MongoDB?

```
db.collection 'one', (err, one) ->
    one.#do stuff
    db.collection 'two', (err, two) ->
        two.#do stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

This is (as far as I am aware) the simplest way of doing things in MongoDB and Node.js.

In your example `one` will contain the results of the first query, and `two` the results of the second.

If you are doing a lot of nested queries, where the nested query does not depend on the results of the outer query, you could consider using the [Async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) (or an alternative) to parallelise the query.